# What is the confidence interval if I compute the total number of bits based on the average number of bits in sampled bins?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean

Let's say I want to estimate the total number N marbles among M sacks of marbles.  The marbles are assumed to be normally distributed.  I can't count them all, so I decide to sample S sacks.  I get the mean # of marbles from the S sacks, then assume it to be the mean for the M sacks, and multiply.  How far off am I from N, as a function of the size of S?  How confident can I be?

Comment: What does "The marbles are assumed to be normally distributed." mean here? Does this mean the *number of marbles per sack* are assumed to be normally distributed? Are negative numbers of marbles per sack permitted (normal distribution goes $\infty to \infty$)?

Comment: good point. by, "normally distributed", I suppose I just mean that most sacks have a middling amount of marbles, tapering towards zero (some will have zero), and then tapering towards some unknown bigger number.

Answer (score 0):

For sample size of $n$ normally distributed values $X_1,...,X_n$,

You calculate the sample mean $\bar X$ and sample variance $S_x^2$.

You have $\frac{\bar X-E(X)}{S_x/\sqrt n}\sim t(df=n-1)$ a t-distribution.

You can construct a $95\%$ CI of $E(X)$ as $\bar X\pm S_x/\sqrt n \times t(0.975,n-1)$.

Based on the $95\%$ CI of $E(X)$ you can calculate the total number of $N$ marbles among $M$ sacks.